# entropy of normal distribution

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory

What is the entropy of a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance \sigma?
Thanks!

Comment: Typing the question into Google seems to give plenty of leads; also, Wikipedia looks to have answers that seem a bout right. Voting to close.

Comment: Fine work on the World Cup.   http://www1.voanews.com/english/news/sports/Psychic-Octopus-Predicts-Spain-World-Cup-Win-98120159.html  


Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [here](http://www.cis.hut.fi/ahonkela/dippa/node94.html) that "the negative differential entropy of the normal distribution"
(which may not be what you are asking for?) is:
$$-\frac{1}{2} [ \log (2 \pi \sigma^2 ) + 1 ] ,$$
independent of $\mu$.

Comment: That's what I got too when i manually derived the formula of E[log(p(x))]. however, the wikipedia formula for entropy of a normal distribution differs by a term of 1/2... Would you have some insight on why that is?

Thanks,

-Octi

Comment: Octopus: Wikipedia is a big site. Care to tell us exactly what page you are looking at with a link?  At http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution the table on the right at the top lists the entropy as $(1/2)\log(2\pi{e}\sigma^2)$, which is the same thing as $(1/2)log(2\pi\sigma^2) + 1/2$ since $\log(e) = 1$. So this is the same formula Joseph gives up to an overall minus sign (I wouldn't use "negative" entropy; the standard entropy formula should have an overall minus sign in it which cancels out that negative sign.)

Comment: @KConrad: Thanks for responding while I was out of touch!  Yes, I think the discrepancy can be resolved by manipulations of $\log(e)$ and minus signs.

Comment: Ok I apologize I didn't see that Joseph's formula didn't have the e in the log argument. Thanks KConrad for pointing that out!
Now this seems to be consistent everywhere!